# findViewById failing to build WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, findviewbyid

```
public class FeedFragment extends Fragment {
private WebView livestream;


public FeedFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

    livestream = (WebView) WebView.findViewById(R.id.livestream);
    livestream.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
```

Why am I getting the following errors:

> error: non-static method findViewById(int) cannot be referenced from a static context
>   where T is a type-variable:
>   T extends View declared in method findViewById(int)

I'm tired of wasting my time reading the android documentation and coming up with errors!

Fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffb067"
tools:context=".FeedFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Feed Fragment" />

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/livestream"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Read about classes before using them . I think you should start from basics of Java.

Comment: `@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false); 
    livestream = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.livestream);
    livestream.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
    return view;
}`

Comment: Could you show how do you create and use FeedFragment? and @ADM right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        livestream = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.livestream);
        livestream.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```

and delete these lines from onCreateView :

```
livestream = (WebView) WebView.findViewById(R.id.livestream);
livestream.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Why delete? May be just move these lines before return?

Comment: Dima your way can also work . But doing it in  `onViewCreated()` is to make use of Fragment's life cycle methods . Ultimately both will work .

Comment: Build still fails error: cannot find symbol class Nullable

Comment: @Tiredofcode please add your error log and your fragment xml.

Comment: Addded xml file @fatemeh-fallahi-arezoudar

Comment: @fatemeh-fallahi-arezoudar When nullable is removed code runs but it not takes you away from the app not loads in the app -_-

Comment: @Tiredofcode what is your app build.gradle support library version?

Comment: `@Nullable` is an annotation you need to import it .

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this livestream = (WebView) WebView.findViewById(...)
With
livestream = (WebView) findViewById(...)

Answer (score 0):

To make a WebView load inline use this code Thanks to all the help everyone

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    livestream = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.livestream);
    livestream.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    livestream.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
```